# Trouble handling a NetCDF4 file

Tags: python, netcdf

I have trouble working with a NetCDF4 file. Can anyone please help me. Reading it in seems to work.

```
import netCDF4
f = netCDF4.Dataset('mydata.nc', 'r')
```

When I try to investigate what's inside the file (>>> print f), I get some information:

```
<type 'netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF4 file format):
dimensions: soundings, levels
variables: 
groups: Retrieval, Sounding
```

...

```
print f.dimensions
```

gives me:

```
OrderedDict([(u'soundings', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x2bd24b0>), 
(u'levels', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x2bd2500>)])
```

From what I read in tutorials I should be able to check the length of the different dimensions by typing

```
print len(soundings)
```

But I receive the error message "name 'soundings' is not defined". Does anybody know what I might do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because you haven't defined a variable named `soundings`.  If you define this variable by

```
soundings = f.dimensions[u'soundings']
```

then you should be able to find the length of `soundings` using `print len(soundings)`.

Alternatively, you can access the length of the 'soundings' dimension directly by using

```
print len(f.dimensions[u'soundings'])
```

I have to admit, I've not used netCDF4, so I read the [netCDF4 documentation](http://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4-module.html) briefly.  In the section 'Dimensions in a netCDF file' it contains the following example of displaying the dimensions of a netCDF4 dataset:

```
>>> print rootgrp.dimensions
OrderedDict([('level', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x1b48030>),
             ('time', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x1b481c0>),
             ('lat', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x1b480f8>),
             ('lon', <netCDF4.Dimension object at 0x1b48a08>)])
```

(For brevity, I've omitted the details about where `rootgrp` comes from.)
The next line of code in the following code fragment is this:

```
>>> print len(lon)
```

What you might have missed is that the variable `lon` was declared further up, as

```
>>> lon = rootgrp.createDimension('lon', 144)
```

The above section of tutorial deals with *creating* new dimensions in a netCDF file, whereas you are reading existing dimensions from a netCDF file.  You must therefore fetch the dimensions out of the netCDF file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went through the netCDF documentation for more than one hour, found the above given example but could not understand it. As you assumed totally correct I just was not able to realize that one step in the code is missing. Now I know what to do. Thanks.